Recyclerview lento al hacer scroll
Cuando pongo (setHasStableIds(true)) solo, hace scroll rapido pero me repite Items y cuando lo pongo con:
 @Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    String a=mData.get(position).getIdentificador();
    int b=Integer.parseInt(a);
    Long c= new Long(b);
    return c;
}

Me sale lento como estaba sin (setHasStableIds(true))
TODO ESTO DENTRO DE MI ADAPTADOR!!
public class Adapter_Pelicula extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_Pelicula.myviewholder>{

private final Context mContext;
private final List<Objeto_Pelicula> mData;

public Adapter_Pelicula(Context mContext, List<Objeto_Pelicula> mData) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mData = mData;
    setHasStableIds(true);
}



No pude poner el código completo de la clase Adapter_Pelicula, la información viene de una lista en otra clase, el objeto película tiene un atributo string Identificador. Intente también (mData.get(position).hashCode()) y nada.
